# How to filter loaded data by jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am fetching data using jquery `load` method. It is working fine. But problem is, it is showing all data that fetched by `load` function. I want to show only specific data. For example it fetch `id`, `name`, `team_message`, `sender`, `created_at`and shows all those data in the div. Now I want to show `name` and `team_message`only in the div. Here is my jquery code

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var id=$('#projectId').val();
$( "#team-messageid" ).load( "/teammessage/"+id);
},1000);
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id="team-messageid">

</div>
```

Here is my Controller code.

```
public function teamMessage($id){
    $projectId = $id;
    $teamChatInfo = DB::table('team_chats')
        ->join('users', 'team_chats.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('team_chats.*', 'team_chats.team_message','users.name')
        ->where('projectproposal_id',$projectId)
        ->get();
        return Response::json(['success'=>$teamChatInfo]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I have solved this problem. That is, I have changed my controller like this.

```
public function teamMessage($id){
    $projectId = $id;
    $teamChatInfo = DB::table('team_chats')
        ->join('users', 'team_chats.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('team_chats.*', 'team_chats.team_message','users.name')
        ->where('projectproposal_id',$projectId)
        ->get();
        if($teamChatInfo){
        foreach ($teamChatInfo as $key => $chat) {
            echo '<span class="">'.$chat->name.'</span>';
            echo "</br>";
            echo '<span class="" style="background-color:red;">' . $chat->team_message . '</span>';
            echo "</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the id in the ajax load response, just get what you need:

```
public function teamMessage($id){
$projectId = $id;
$teamChatInfo = DB::table('team_chats')
    ->join('users', 'team_chats.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('team_chats.*', 'team_chats.team_message','users.name')
    ->where('projectproposal_id',$projectId)
    ->get(['name, team_message']);
    return Response::json(['success'=>$teamChatInfo]);
}
```

It is not clear how you actually parse the data into the team-messageid div. My answer my be inconclusive because of it.

Comment: Actually I need those data so I can't ignore fetching those data.